# Objective-C: override dynamic getter

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, overriding, getter

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass `MyClass` with a property `myProp`, which is defined `@dynamic`. There are various instances of reading `myProp` in my code, via `[myClass myProp]`.

Now, I want to define a getter (that returns `myProp` after appending something to it) for `myProp`, without changing the various calls to [myClass myProp]. i.e. without creating a getter that is named something other than `getMyProp`.

My question is, if I create a getter `getMyProp`, which will override the getter created by `NSManagedObject`, how do I access the original value that is stored in the database?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To access the underlying values of a managed object you use the following two methods:

[- (id)primitiveValueForKey:(NSString *)key](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/primitiveValueForKey:)

[- (void)setPrimitiveValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/setPrimitiveValue:forKey:)

This is often used to convert NSNumber attributes into their 'real' type, for example a bool property:

```
- (BOOL)isShared
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"isShared"];
    NSNumber *underlyingValue = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"isShared"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"isShared"];
    return [underlyingValue boolValue];
}
```

The `willAccessValueForKey:` and `didAccessValueForKey:` are required by the underlying managed object class for handling faults and relationships etc.

And if you do end up writing a setter, you must also wrap the accessor in KVC methods:

```
- (void)setShared:(BOOL)isShared
{
    NSNumber *newUnderlyingValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isShared];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isShared"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:newUnderlyingValue forKey:@"isShared"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isShared"];
}
```

Having said this, I would personally not recommend you keep the same method name unless you have a good reason. For 'derived' values you generally want to create a brand new method with a different name. It doesn't take long to do a quick find/replace throughout your code.

EDIT: added willAccessValueForKey:/didAccessValueForKey: (thanks jrturton)

Comment: Do you also need to bracket your getter code with `willAccessValueForKey:` and `didAccessValueForKey:` to ensure that faults are fired if necessary?

Comment: hey, this one's a few months old now but, should't your example setter be "setIsShared" (not "setShared")?  Just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something.